# Can a non-selectable menu heading be created using lightning:menuItem?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds

This [Dynamic List](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/menus/#flavor-dynamic-list-0-items) SLDS example has a nicely formatted "MY FAVORITES" heading that is not selectable and does not highlight.

I'm using the [lightning:buttonMenu (Beta)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_buttonMenu.htm)
 and [lightning:menuItem (Beta)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_menuItem.htm) components and haven't found a way to achieve the same effect with them. Is there a way to show a non-selectable heading in the menu when using those components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding the heading like this (the `<h3>...</h3>`) seems to work:

```
<lightning:buttonMenu class="slds-m-around--xx-small"
                      iconSize="x-small"
                      title="{! v.title }"
                      alternativeText="{! v.title }"
                      onselect="{! c.handleMenuSelect }"
                      menuAlignment="{! v.align }"
                      >
    <h3 class="slds-text-title--caps slds-p-around--small" role="presentation">{! v.title }</h3>
    <lightning:menuItem label="Select" value="SELECT" iconName="utility:list"/>
    <lightning:menuItem label="Add Before" value="ADD_BEFORE" class="slds-has-divider--top-space"/>
    <lightning:menuItem label="Add After" value="ADD_AFTER" />
    <lightning:menuItem label="Move to Top" value="MOVE_TOP" iconName="utility:jump_to_top" class="slds-has-divider--top-space"/>
    <lightning:menuItem label="Move Up" value="MOVE_UP"/>
    <lightning:menuItem label="Move Down" value="MOVE_DOWN"/>
    <lightning:menuItem label="Move to Bottom" value="MOVE_BOTTOM" iconName="utility:jump_to_bottom"/>
    <lightning:menuItem label="Remove" value="REMOVE" iconName="utility:close" class="slds-has-divider--top-space"/>
</lightning:buttonMenu>
```

and `class="slds-has-divider--top-space"` adds dividing lines.